# Image component cannot display online image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Users information comes over a SOAP service to Flex app and it displays the avatar of the specific user. However when the application run nothing is shown. The path of images are in an array and it is assigned to the source of image but not works really. On the other hand when I give it like link itself it works.

```
stu_avatar.source = Info.repStuArr[Info._StuList].avatar;//it shows empty

stu_avatar.source = "http://extremelifechanger.com/web_images/avatar-sam09-8-251.jpg";//when change to this, it displays the image
```

also I can get the link right when;

```
trace(Info.repStuArr[Info._StuList].avatar);
```

How can I display the avatars of users which are kept in that array?

Comment: Have you check link you get have image? try to to get `Info.repStuArr[Info._StuList].avatar` into string and apply that string to `stu_avatar.source`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Interestingly when I assign `Info.repStuArr[Info._StuList].avatar` to a new `String` var and then give it as a source, it works. So why does it behave like that?

Comment: I thing that value you are getting not in string. Try `stu_avatar.source = (Info.repStuArr[Info._StuList].avatar).toString();`

Comment: Gotcha! I parsed the `xml` and the path as text. When I cast it to `String` and it is done. If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get `Info.repStuArr[Info._StuList].avatar` into string and apply that string to `stu_avatar.source`

Like:

```
var str:String = Info.repStuArr[Info._StuList].avatar;
stu_avatar.source = str;
```

Or try:

```
stu_avatar.source = (Info.repStuArr[Info._StuList].avatar).toString();
```